# How find real solutions to second-order linear ODE's with 3 regular singular points

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the inhomogeneous ODE

$-r(x-m)y'(x) + S(x)y''(x) = \beta,$

where $r,m,\beta > 0$ and $S$ is a quadratic polynomial with negative discriminant. For the sake of the question it may be okay consider the homogeneous case $\beta = 0$.

It seems the 'standard' method of solving this is viewing the ODE as complex (or rather on the Riemann sphere), determining the singular points and deciding whether they are regular.

A variable transformation $z := \frac{x - \lambda}{\bar \lambda - \lambda}$, where $\lambda$ is a zero of $S$ yields the hypergeometric equation

$$u''(z) + \left(\frac{\gamma}{z} + \frac{1-\gamma +\alpha}{z-1}\right) u'(z) = \frac{\beta}{sz(z-1)},$$
for some real $\alpha$ and some, not necessarily real $\gamma$.

One solution for $\beta = 0$ is of course the constant $1$. Another one is given by

$$u_h(z) := z^{1-\gamma}\,_2F_1(1-\gamma, 1-\gamma+\alpha, 2-\gamma; z).$$

A particular solution to inhomogeneous equation is given by
$$u_p(z) := -\frac{\beta}{s\gamma}z\cdot _3F_2(1,1,\alpha+1,2,\gamma+1;z),$$
and so the general solution is
$$u(z) = c_1 + c_2z^{1-\gamma}\,_2F_1(1-\gamma, 1-\gamma+\alpha, 2-\gamma; z) -\frac{\beta}{s\gamma}z\cdot\,_3F_2(1,1,\alpha+1,2,\gamma+1;z).$$

In the end we re-substitute $y(x) = u((\bar \lambda  - \lambda) z + \lambda)$ to get the general solution of our original ODE.

Now, *my question*:

In the end I need a real solution. We could start computing the real part of $y$ and get a new basis for the homogeneous solution space or try to pick $c_1,c_2$ to make $y$ real, but this seems not only cumbersome - I straight up don't know how to make this work. With all this information in mind:

> How do I find a **real** solution of $-r(x-m)y'(x) + S(x)y''(x) = \beta$?

If possible I also like to see the most 'convenient' way. I'm not sure it even involves the complex domain at all.

PS: I know we can reduce the ODE to a first-order ODE with $w := y'$, but then we have to integrate a product of a "polynomial" and a hypergeometric function to get $y$. If this is just the way to go, I can be convinced of that too. Although, it would be a bit disappointing to find out that this method fails completely if we have a $q(x)y(x)$ term as well.

Answer (score 0):

The paper by Norbert Euler (1997) ``Transformation Properties of $\ddot{x}+f_1(t)\dot{x} + f_2(t)x + f_3(t) x^n = 0$" Journal of Nonlinear Mathematical Physics, 4:3-4, 310-337
describes in detail the "*the most general conditions on the functions $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$, by which the equation may be integrable, as well as conditions for the existence of Lie point symmetries.*"

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I know that a solution exists, I even know it has the form of $u(z)$ in my answer. My question: how do real solutions look like - as concretely as possible, e.g. what constraints does this put on the constants $c_1,c_2$?